# What is the original (Judeo-Arabic) of "gates of interpretation are not locked before us" in Moreh Nevuchim?

Tags: rambam, arabic

What is the original phrasing of the "gates of interpretation are not locked before us" (i.e. ולא שערי הפירוש סתומים בפנינו) in Guide to the Perplexed 2:25?  That is, what is it in Rambam's Judeo-Arabic?

Comment: You might also consider the recent (authoritative) translation available for free: http://press.tau.ac.il/perplexed/chapters/chap_2_25.htm

Answer (score 9):

There's an edition containing (only) the original Judeo-Arabic on [Seforim Online](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/217.pdf). Assuming that what you're looking for is what's translated in [this Hebrew translation](http://press.tau.ac.il/perplexed/chapters/chap_2_25.htm) as

> וגם אין שערי הפירוש בעניין חידוש העולם נעולים בפנינו ולא נמנעים ממנו

The relevant line in the Judeo-Arabic seems to be on page 229 of the book (found on page 131 of the PDF), line 10:

> ולא אבואב אלתאויל איצא מסדודה פי וגׄוהנא ולא ממתנעה עלינא פי אמר חדותׄ אלעלם

Caveats:

- I'm not certain that I picked the exact right end of the phrase.
- There are symbols over some of the letters that are not available with the local Hebrew keyboard.

Comment: Erm can anyone find the correct image?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I gave it a shot. I'm pretty confident in the beginning of the phrase, since "וגם אין שערי הפירוש," [GTranslated to Arabic](https://translate.google.com/#iw/ar/%D7%95%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9), yields something that starts out sounding "ולא אבואב," and the [footnote](http://press.tau.ac.il/perplexed/footnotes/chap_2_25_ft.htm#2) in the Hebrew on "הפירוש" refers to "תאויל." It might be worth checking my transcription and also seeing if you can confirm the phrase-end.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Will try. If I haven't done so by Nisan ping me again.

Comment: @DoubleAA If I haven't pinged you by Iyyar, remind me.

Comment: @IsaacMoses From what I can tell (with help from Google Translate), your endpoint appears to be correct; אלעלם corresponds to העולם, and ימכננא תאויל corresponds to יכולים לפרש. The Hebrew translation you provided rearranged the words; following the original word order would yield Hebrew more like: "וגם אין שערי הפירוש נעולים בפנינו ולא נמנעים ממנו בעניין חידוש העולם".

Answer (score 7):

The word that is translated פירוש is تَأْوِيل taʾwīl, an infinitive from the second form of the root أول. Here are a few of the definitions given in Lane's Lexicon:

> -The turning of a verse of the Kurʾan from its apparent meaning to a meaning which it bears, or admits.
>
> -Rendering in a manner not according to the letter, or overt sense; explaining the covert, or virtual meaning; interpreting in a manner
>   not according to the obvious meaning.
>
> -Explaining the meaning of that which is equivocal or ambiguous, i.e., what is not understood without repeated consideration.

Comment: I believe he was looking for the original phrase, [which was provided by Alex](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6322/5).

Comment: Yes, of course. I just assumed it would be relevant to add some explanation and would make the question and answer more useful.